# Function which measures time M times

Tags: python, function, time, python-itertools

I am to measure how much time does it take for the function below to represent: C in range [0, 10] with the numbers in list N. (M measurements for each C).

```
import itertools
def amount(C):
    N = [1, 2, 5]
    #N = list(N)
    N = sorted(N)
    while C < max(N):
        N.remove(max(N))
    res = []
    for i in range(1, C):
        for j in list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(N, i)):
            res.append(sum(list(j)))
    m = 0
    for z in range (0, len(res)):
        if res[z] == C:
            m += 1
    if N[0] == 1:
        return m + 1 
    else:
       return m
```

EDITED:

```
import itertools
def amount(C):
    N = [1, 2, 5]
    res = []
    for i in range(1, C):
        for j in list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(N, i)):
            res.append(sum(list(j)))
    m = 0
    for z in range (0, len(res)):
        if res[z] == C:
            m += 1
    if N[0] == 1:
        return m + 1 
    else:
       return m
```

I would like to make 10 measurements and then take for example median of all those measurements.

There is my code but something unfortunately doesn't work properly and I have no idea what is wrong:

```
import time
def time_counter(amount, n=11, M=11):
    res = list(range(n))
    def count_once():
        start = time.perf_counter()
        amount(res)
        return time.perf_counter() - start
    return [count_once() for m in range(M)]
```

Comment: _"but something unfortunately doesn't work properly"_. How do you know? Are you getting an error message? If so, what is it? Are you getting output that you don't expect? If so, what output are you getting, and what output do you expect? Are you getting no output at all? Possibly it's because you're not actually calling `time_counter` at any point. Or, if you are calling `time_counter` but just didn't show us all of your code, please actually show us all of your code.

Comment: It may save you some effort to use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) instead of writing your own function timing code.

Comment: I'm getting an error message, here it is: **can only concatenate list (not "int") to list**.
And that's all my code. There is only the function "amount" and then that one which should measure the time.

Comment: @Kevin That might be quite a good solution! I haven't known about timeit.

Comment: _"And that's all my code."_ No, something must be missing. When I run exactly the code you have shared here, I don't get that error. [I don't get any error at all](http://ideone.com/ATUTMk), in fact.

Comment: @Hendrra here in function amount `C` is an array  and max(N) is int how are you suppoed to compare those in the `while` loop ?

Comment: @Kevin now I'm so confused.. Because it's working... lol. However I'm not sure if the result is what I expect. Because that code is returning M measurements for just one C, isn't it?

Comment: @Sarathsp that's true there is a mistake. N used to be something else and I didn't change it. Sorry!

Comment: @Hendrra if you could change it i may try checking my answer. I seem to know the reason but int he code you shared the problem won't happen as it ill halt before reaching list + int

Comment: @Sarathsp thank you very much! Give me a sec.

Comment: @Sarathsp the code is done. However I just deleted those lines with max(N). Something isn't work there and I have another code (more optimized one which will be used in my project). That one is just as an example. And now it's working.. but I'm not sure what the time function is returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are again passing a list and trying to do `range(1,C)` where `C` is a list

Here is how your program should be

```
import itertools
import time    
def amount(C):
    N = [1, 2, 5]
    res = []
    for i in range(1, C):
        for j in list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(N, i)):
            res.append(sum(list(j)))
    m = 0
    for z in range (0, len(res)):
        if res[z] == C:
            m += 1
    if N[0] == 1:
        return m + 1 
    else:
       return m

def time_counter(amount, n=11, M=11):
    res = list(range(n))
    def count_once(c):
        start = time.perf_counter()
        amount(c)
        return time.perf_counter() - start
    return [count_once(m) for m in range(M)]

#testing
print(time_counter(amount))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I really appreciate your help. However I don't understand one thing/

Comment: (sorry, I'm using different keyboard this week and it's pretty hard). As I wrote I don't understand one think. The function is returning 11 measurements for one C and C = 11, yes?

Comment: This solves the problem you  had in the question .I did not look at the logic. Problem on logic would make it a very specific question and would not be a question eligible for stackoverflow

Comment: `C` is passed as any value from o to 10 , in the last line of that function. If you want 11 give `n` as the arguement to `amount(n)` inside count_once function

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I wanted :)

Comment: @Hendrra Can you please upvote or accept the answer if that helped you ?